# Need to find difference between numbers in array and save to new array - novice

Tags: java, arrays

I am frankly a novice to Java. I have a project that i am working on where I want to find a way to create a polynomial function based on a sequence of numbers.

Anyway, my question is that i have created an array that has stored a sequence. I would like to now find the difference between the elements. So for example. i want to find this calculation `a[2] - a[1]` and then store accordingly into another array.

What i have already done is this. I am not too confident about this but mostly am having a problem storing each into another array. I am sure this is a bit of a stupid question however, I would appreciate any help possible.

```
for(int i = 0;i<=sequence.length;i++){
    double diff = sequence[i+1]- sequence[i];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `sequence` is an array of `double`s, try this:

```
double[] diffs = new double[sequence.length - 1];
for (int i = 0; i < sequence.length - 1; i++) {
    diffs[i] = sequence[i + 1] - sequence[i];
}
```

Comment: @Ray It will work. Length = 10, i = 8 will be the last to be used.

Comment: Oh. this is awesome. I can't believe i didn't think of this. thankyou so much guys . You are fantastic. Thankyou very much, Just got me out of a jam,

Comment: yeah. i don't really know how to. but as soon as i find out. i definitely will.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = new int[sequence.length - 1];
// length will be smaller by 1 than the original sequence

for(int i = 0; i < sequence.length - 1; i++){
   arr[i] = sequence[i+1]- sequence[i]; // no point making it double 
   //if both elements are ints, they won't have decimals to use in calculation.
}
```